# Unable to INSERT with Pymysql (incremental id changes though)

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

When I'm using pymysql to perform operations on MySQL database, it seems that all the operations are temporary and only visible to the pymysql connection, which means I can only see the changes through `cur.execute('select * from qiushi')` and once I `cur.close()` and `conn.close()` and log back in using pymysql, everything seems unchanged.

However, when I'm looking at the incremental id numbers, it does increased, but I can't see the rows that were inserted from pymysql connection. It seems that they were automatically deleted?!

Some of my code is here:

`import pymysql
try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',port=3306,user='pymysql',passwd='pymysql',charset='utf8')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    #cur.execute('CREATE TABLE qiushi (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, content_id BIGINT(10) NOT NULL, content VARCHAR(1000), created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY(id));')
    #cur.execute('DESCRIBE content')
    #cur.fetchall()
    cur.execute('USE qiushibaike')
    for _ in range(0,len(content_ids)):
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO qiushi (content,content_id) VALUES (\"%s\",%d)"%(jokes[_],int(content_ids[_])))
finally:
    cur.close()
    conn.close()`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by myself...
Because the config is automatically committed, so after each SQL sentence we should commit the changes.

Approach 1:
add `cur.commit()` after the `cur.execute()`

Approach 2:
edit the connection config, add `autocommit=True`